# What is a performant algorithm for implementing APL grade up?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, apl

For APLers: I am only concerned with monadic grade up over vectors.

For non-APLers: Grade up is a function that takes a numeric vector *V* of size *n* and returns an integer vector *R* of equal size.  The index of the smallest element of *V* is placed in *R*[0], the index of the next smallest element in *R*[1], ..., the largest element of *V* in *R*[*n*-1].  The value of *V* must be unchanged.

Grading is obviously related to sorting: *R* provides the indices into *V* to access *V* in sorted order.  Grade up must be stable: that is, if two elements of *V* with indices *i, j* where *i* < *j* are equal, then *i, j* will appear consecutively in *R* and in that order.  An O(*n*^2) implementation is easy, but I don't see how to adapt a standard stable O(*n* log *n*) sorting implementation for this purpose.  An algorithm using only constant space would be desirable.

Comment: https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/implementation/primitive/sort.html could be a useful resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular task, you can use any in-place sorting algorithm:  Fill R with the indexes from 0 to n-1, and then just sort it.

For the sort, instead of comparing two indexes *i* and *j* by value, you compare *V[i]* to *V[j]*.  If they are equal, *then* break the tie by comparing *i* and *j*.

Since no two indexes will compare equal, even an unstable algorithm like Quicksort will produce stable results.  Many languages include a default sort that takes a comparison function as input.

Comment: You are correct, I completely forgot that you can compare indexes to make the sort stable.